# Error while installing xdebug syntax error in php.ini

Tags: php

I'm trying to install xdebug and I got this error when I'm checking my extensions with "PHP -m" in cmd :

> C:\Users\AMIR>php -m
>   PHP:  syntax error, unexpected END_OF_LINE, expecting '=' in C:\xampp\php\php.ini on line 2002

How can I solve this problem and install xdebug?

PS: This is my PHP.ini code :
[image: php.ini code picture]

Answer (score 1):

You have a space before the `[XDebug]` remove it.

Comment: [Online demo](https://3v4l.org/ZkVgf).